# Edit navigation bar in storyboard after segue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have the following situation with 2 `View Controllers` (**A** & **B**), where **A** is embedded in a `Navigation Controller` and there is a `show segue` that connects **A** to **B**. 
[image]
I am able to play with the **A**'s `Navigation Bar`, setting the title and adding buttons from the storyboard. But this is not true for **B**, I can only make edits programmatically

```
self.title = "VCB"
```

works and displays the title beside the back button of the navigation controller to **A**), but I cannot physically select the `Navigation Bar` to set a Title or add BarButton from storyboard. 
 
I was just wondering if there is a way to edit **B**'s `Navigation Bar` from the storyboard?

Comment: what issue you are facing when adding button or title to ViewcontrollerB?. Be specific

Comment: The above one you mentioned is a behavior of `UINavigationController` .Because root view can be configured which is first in the memory stack , the other child view are will be maintained in stack during the execution so they are not allowed to edit in storyboard

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are workaround

1. just add new Navigation Controller for B
2. write the Title and put any buttons in B Navigation Bar
3. Delete the new Navigation Controller for B

Done

Answer (score 0):

1, Make B embed in navi

2, Delete navi

3, Make A to B push segue